# Waiting for LocalHost loading never ends

Tags: apache, wamp, wampserver

i've correctly installed WampServer 2.5 on my Windows 7 64bit system.

WampServer icon is Green, after i click on Start all Services and click on phpMyAdmin it opens a tab or a new window in my browser (i'm using Chrome) and the page does not load and stay all the time without ending by "Waiting for LocalHost" loading.

I really need to get this work, i've already unchecked the Skype box about the ports use, and close the Skype app too when i'm launching WampServer.

I've already checked using in the cmd the netstat -aon command if there was any other application using the port 80, bu other then Wamp no process or app is using that port.

To make easy, the Access log of Apache is blank, and here below is reported the Apache error log:

```
[Thu Jan 08 13:46:57.143005 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4696:tid 372] AH00422: Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
[Thu Jan 08 13:46:59.153014 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4760:tid 292] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited.
[Thu Jan 08 13:46:59.293014 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4696:tid 372] AH00430: Parent: Child process 4760 exited successfully.
[Thu Jan 08 13:47:05.877582 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5676:tid 372] AH00455: Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Jan 08 13:47:05.877582 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5676:tid 372] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Mar 16 2014 12:42:59
[Thu Jan 08 13:47:05.877582 2015] [core:notice] [pid 5676:tid 372] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\wamp\\bin\\apache\\apache2.4.9\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9'
[Thu Jan 08 13:47:05.887582 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5676:tid 372] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 5208
[Thu Jan 08 13:47:06.651603 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5208:tid 292] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Thu Jan 08 13:47:06.671603 2015] [mpm_winnt:error] [pid 5208:tid 820] (OS 10038)Tentativo di operazione su un elemento diverso dal socket. : AH00332: winnt_accept: getsockname error on listening socket, is IPv6 available?
```

Comment: Try accessing it through 127.0.0.1 just to see if it works.

Answer (score 3):

Try doing from the command line (as Administrator) :

```
netsh winsock reset
```

and **restart WampServer**.

The OS10038 error in your error log file seems to point to a TCP/IP stack windows problem.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome does something odd with localhost, I guess to protect Joe Public from something !?!?!?

There appear to be a number of possible solutions, but this one seem to be the current favorite :-

```
Go to 
chrome://flags 
and set 
"Built-in Asynchronous DNS" to "Disabled", then restart the browser.
```

If as @rtome suggests you do actually have a TCP/IP stack issue this is a more comprehensive solution to reseting all that

```
Open a command prompt as Administrator

Run

netsh winsock reset
netsh winsock reset catalog
netsh int ip reset reset.log
netsh int ipv4 reset reset.log
netsh int ipv6 reset reset.log
ipconfig /flushdns

Reboot if necessary

Try apache again
```

Answer (score 0):

Clearing my cookies solved a similar continuous loading for me.

Answer (score -1):

If you are on Windows, and have used

```
php artisan serve
```

you need to close CMD (or shell) black window to close server socket.

Now open new CMD window and issue php artisan serve. Windows sometimes fails to release socket when we press CTRL+C and terminate the server.

Comment: This is an answer for Laravel based websites only